# rails - retrieve certain values from array

Tags: ruby-on-rails, arrays

I am calling an api to get a response.

```
users = response.involved_users // here users is an array with everything, I only want the actual user numbers
```

Part of this response has an array.

The array can have one or more elements.

In each element, there are values of

```
@type = "start"
@value = "this value"
@user = "12345"
```

I don't know if these are stored as a hash in the elements or what.

I want to pull all the `@user` - user numbers in to an array.

So for every elemnent, add the user to an array.

so this line, user should be an array of users:

```
users = response.involved_users // do I need to do a map?
```

I tried this:

```
users = response.involved_users.map { |x| x[:user]
```

but got this:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `[]' for #<Client::InvolvedUser:0x11691828>:
```

Comment: it should be ``x.user``.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    #<Client::InvolvedUser:0x11691828>:
```

shows that x is an object of Class Client::InvolvedUser so an object's attribute should be called like this

```
    x.user
```

Try this

```
    users = response.involved_users.map { |x| x.user }
```